# Show Hide for UILabel over constraint not working as expected for height constraint

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, uilabel

I have `UILabel` which I am showing and hiding on `tapGesture`.
I have created label programatically and set constraint programatically only.

by default UILabel is visible with `heightConstraint = 230`
on tapGesture method I am making `heightConstraint = 0` and its hiding label correctly.
Again on tapGesture I need to show label,
so when I tap again, I can see `heightConstraint = 230` again, but label is not seen in UI.

What might be issue, only hide is working and show is not working.

Following is the code for tapGesture method where I am setting height constraints.

```
@objc func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap working")
        isExpanded.toggle()
        if(isExpanded){
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                reminderBulletsLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 230)
            ])
        }else{
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                reminderBulletsLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
            ])
        }
    }
```

I tried to deactivate the constraint but not working.

Please find the screen shot attached.

1. Default state when label is seen

[image]

2. On Click, when label is hidden.

[image]

now after clicking again label is not showing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can either create a "heightConstraint" property and update its `.constant` value, or you can create two height constraints... one `equalToConstant: 230` and the other `equalToConstant: 0` and then activate/deactivate (or change priorities).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just sorted the issue.
The issue was I was declaring
var heightCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
as local.

I just declare the same in Global.

Following is the code sorted the issue.

```
var heightCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
    @objc func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        isExpanded.toggle()
        if let constraint = heightCon{
            constraint.isActive = false
        }
        heightCon = reminderBulletsLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: isExpanded ? 230 : 0)
        heightCon.isActive = true
    }
```

Thanks @Sh_Khan for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to keep an instance of the height constraint don't create new height constraint every time. like this

```
var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

and inside the viewDidLoad add this

```
constraint = label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250)
constraint?.isActive = true
```

then inside tapLabel function add

```
constraint?.constant = isExpanded ? 20 : 250
```

**Second**  the most important thing when you make your height 0 you can't tap it anymore because the label height is zero then how you can tap something has zero height if you make it 20 like the example i provided the label will be clickable if you want to hide the label completely maybe you need to take another approach  than tapping the label

Comment: I have one title label and one description label.
Title label is having tapGesture. on which I am showing and hiding the descriptionLabel.